# ASP.NET: How to Append Rows at the end of ListView for a "Load More" Functionality?

Tags: asp.net, listview, load, append

I have a List View which has some dynamic HTML inside it, what I want to do is display 10 records each time I click the Load More Button but the problem is that each time I fetch new records they are replaced by the old ones, they're aren't appended atthe end.

I have a List View with an ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ListView .... DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" />
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div id="content" runat="server">
     // Some dynamically generated HTML
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here's my Object Data Source:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetActivities" TypeName="MyLocation >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="pageSize" DefaultValue="10" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pageNumber" DefaultValue="0" Type="Int32" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here's the code for my LoadMore button:

```
this.ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["pageNumber"].DefaultValue = (int.Parse(this.ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["pageNumber"].DefaultValue) + 1).ToString();
```

This increases the Page Number each time I click the LoadMore button which in turns fetches the next page records, but the problem is that the records are being replaced and I want to append them to the end of the List View.

Comment: Have you considered a client side approach using JQuery - AJAX - REST Services/OData Services?

Comment: @Jupaol My only option at the moment is a Server Side with minor Client side solution, do you know if what I want can be achieved in a server side solution? Thomas suggested CUstom paging but I dont' see how can Custom Paging solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the pageNumber in the LoadMore-method, can't you just increase the pageSize with 10? Maybe nn combination with a updatepanel!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already tried that, the problem with that approach is that ALL the records are fetched each time you click the Laod More button which I found to be slow especially if you're loading many records so I'm looking for a way to fetch only the next 10 records and append them to the end of the ListView.

Comment: @EricBergman I see. Then I think you have to do some server side paging. This can be done with a stored procedure that takes page-size and current page-number as parameters. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=267 these two links does something like that... There are plenty more if you search for server side paging.. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I still have no idea how to achieve what I want with Custom Paging, can you give me hint or an example of what you'd do if faced with this situation? Thank you.